# C++: Call function of Class B when a function of Class A is called (Pointer to Class A is a Member of Class B)

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals, slot

```
class A {
  void functionA();
};

class B {
  A* A_;
  void functionB();
};
```

How can I automatically call `functionB()` in a `class B` instance, if `functionA()` is called outside of the `class B` instance? (Pointer to a `Class A` instance is member of the `class B` instance).
I am looking for something like the SIGNAL/SLOT method in Qt.

Comment: Which instance should execute `functionB` in `functionA`? Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Lookup _Observer Pattern_, callback functions, callback interfaces.

Comment: I have a class (Class A) which represents the description of something that should be visualized by another Class (Class B).
I want to pass Class A once to Class B. But if the description (something in Class A) is changed by a function, I want to automatically trigger the corresponding visualization function in Class B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a [function object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) as a callback. In the following example, B's constructor registers a [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) in the A instance which will be called by A whenever functionA is called. This lambda, in turn, simply calls functionB.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    void functionA() {
        std::cout << "Function A called" << std::endl;
        if (callback_) {
            callback_();
        }
    }

    void setCallback(std::function<void(void)> callback) {
        this->callback_ = callback;
    }

private:
    std::function<void(void)> callback_;
};

class B {
public:
    B(A* a) : A_(a) {
        A_->setCallback([this](){this->functionB();});
    }

    void functionB() {
        std::cout << "Function B called" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    A* A_;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b = B(&a);

    a.functionA();
}
```

The output:

```
Function A called
Function B called
```

As you can see in the output, when a.functionA() is called in main, functionB is also called automatically.